# Send datas from html to controller in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I must send datas from html page (simple form with few input text fields) to page controller and then to database. I am using thymeleaf 2.0.17, spring 3.0. I searched and checked some solutions but didn't work. Maybe someone had the same problem and find some good solution. Please help. Thanks

Comment: if you are searching for example then you can find it here http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html
and if you are facing trouble with something, please rephrase your question stating what is the real problem (viz either in binding,in persistence ..)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can find an example in  http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form.

As the tutorial suggests, you need to use `th:object`, `th:action` and `th:field` to create a form in Thymeleaf.

It looks like this:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.setBar("bar");

  model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
  ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="foo") Foo foo) {
  ...
}
```

html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{bar}" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Foo.java:

```
public class Foo {
  private String bar;

  public String getBar() {
    return bar;
  }

  public void setBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Above link is no more accessible.

Comment: I have fixed the broken link.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the following error: ``Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "fragments/send" - line 21, col 55)`` when I use the ``th:field`` tags on my form.