# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'subscription' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I started working with thymeleaf.

I am following this page: [Spring MVC view layer: Thymeleaf vs. JSP](http://www.thymeleaf.org/thvsjsp.html)

I have got a class:

```
public class MyMainObject {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;

// getters and setters
}
```

I also have got a controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyMainObjectController extends AbstractController 
    @RequestMapping({"/subscribeth"})
    public String getObj(final MyMainObject subscription) {
        return "subscribeth";
    }
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<form action="#" th:object="${subscription}" th:action="@{/subscribeth}">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="a" th:text="#{subscription.a}">a:
            </label> <input type="text" th:field="*{a}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="b" th:text="#{subscription.b}">b:
            </label> <input type="text" th:field="*{b}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="c" th:text="#{subscription.c}">c: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{c}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="d" th:text="#{subscription.d}">d:
            </label> <input type="text" th:field="*{d}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="e" th:text="#{subscription.e}">e:
            </label> <input type="text" th:field="*{e}" />
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit" name="save" th:text="#{subscription.submit}">Subscribe me!</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I run mu application I have an error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring3.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring3.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'subscription' available as request attribute
```

It looks like, I have to create bean `subscription`.

And here is my question, **how I can do that**? I downloaded source code from the tutorial I mentioned before and I cannot find it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate your controller handler method's parameter with `@ModelAttribute("subscription")`. By default, without the value given, Spring will generate an attribute name based on the type of the parameter. Thus `MyMainObject` will become `myMainObject`.

Comment: @Girly And that is the handler method that renders the view called `subscribeth`?

Comment: Still the same error with     `@RequestMapping({"/subscribeth"})
    public String getObj(@ModelAttribute("subscription") final MyMainObject subscription) {
        return "subscribeth";
    }`

Comment: to render this view I am using another method.

Comment: @girly You need to add the model attribute (or request attribute) before the view is rendered, so wherever that handler method is.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the op. I have annotated the argument with @ModelAttribute("response") Response resp but Spring still kicks out the error that it cannot locate the bean named "response"

I do not have any additional configuration files. It's just one Controller class with two methods: one for get requests and one for post requests

Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt how are you using the form?

Comment: <form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/post}" th:object="${response}">
 <p>DK: <input type="number" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /><input type="reset" value="Cancel" /></p>
</form>

Comment: And controller method: @RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getResponse(@RequestParam("response") Response resp, Model model) {  
  model.addAttribute("response", resp);
  return "result";
 }

Comment: @Matt it's the GET handler that's important. Can you post that?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showPatients() {
  return "index";
 }

Comment: The page with the form on it is ridiculously simple for the sake of trying to get this to work. I'm just trying to pass data to the "results" view

Comment: For what it's worth, I also tried, almost verbatim, this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf

But for whatever reason it keeps throwing the same error

Comment: @Matt Your form is looking for a request attribute named `response`, but you don't seem to be adding one. It's your GET handler that needs to do that as it renders the view.

Comment: Aha, I see now. So I have to add the attribute to the model in the GET method in order to request it in the form. Sort of makes sense xD Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner, when I had this problem, It was solved by adding model.addAttribute("modelname", new modelObj()); before returning the view-name, eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLogin(Model model, HttpSession session)
{
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserForm());
    return "users";
}
```