# Spring MCV: Cannot handle data input

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, request-mapping

My goal is to authorization user via handling its login and password. I've tried to reproduce [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf) but faced with problem.

I have an **Entity User** class:

```
@DynamicUpdate
public class EntityUser
{
    String login;
    String password;

    public EntityUser() {}

    public EntityUser
    (
            String login,
            String password
        )
    {   
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is my **.jsp** file fragment:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/loginCheck}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{login}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And this is fragment of my **Controller.java** class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userForm(Model model)
    {
        EntityUser user = new EntityUser();
        user.setLogin("login");
        user.setPassword("password");
        model.addAttribute("user", user);

        System.out.println(user.getLogin());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());

        return "/loginCheck";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processUser(@ModelAttribute(value="user") EntityUser user)
    {

        System.out.println(user.getLogin());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());

        loginInfo = "Jakarta";
        return "redirect:/controllers";
    }
```

After input the values and pushing "Submit" button there is no GET or POST method called (there wasn't any prints in console), and the page is moving to /#

On the other hand, when I replace
`form action="#"`
to
`form action="/HelloSpringMVC/loginCheck"`,
the POST method is called, but both strings printed are "null"

So, what's wrong there? Anybody knows?

**EDITED:**
Here are my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/YdRX9Tiw) and [web.xml](http://pastebin.com/YqDKx0qM) files.

Comment: It doesn't look like thymeleaf is being used to pass the input values into the user object in your model. You're trying to use a mix of view types. JSP and Thymeleaf. You probably want to stick to one or the other. I suggest to stick with thymeleaf, and work the solution that way. Can you include your pom.xml and MVC config classes?

Comment: Pom.xml and web.aml are added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pom.xml doesn't have the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency, so the thymeleaf tags are not being handled in your html/jsp templates. Add the thymeleaf starter dependency in your pom.xml and rebuild:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Thymeleaf will automatically look for templates with .html extension in src/main/resources/templates. You may wish to customize the defaults by editing/creating src/main/resources/application.properties and adding any of the spring.thymeleaf.* application properties defined in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html and tailor these for your own needs.