# Send each list to controller (thymeleaf Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need sone help to send the List produtos as parameter to my controller.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div th:each="produto : ${produtos}" class="form-group" id="produtos">
       <label th:text="${produto.nome}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
       </label>
       <div class="col-sm-1">
           <input type="text" class="form-control js-number" id="quantPedido" 
           th:field="*{produto.quantPedido}"/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvar(@Validated Pedido pedido, List<Produto> produtos, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes attributes) {


}
```

Thanks so Much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send datas from html to controller in Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not work. is different.

Comment: Hi, you need to warp your list of products inside some bean and then send back to the controller that bean with the list of products

Answer (score 0):

You need to warp yours products list into some bean, then send that bean to the html and fill it. Example:

Bean:

```
public class Pedido{
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList();
    //extra attributes
}
```

In your controller:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("yourView");
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
mav.addObject("pedido", pedido);
```

In your html:

```
<form th:object="${pedido}" th:action="@{/savePedido}" method="POST">
    //...
    <div th:each="produto : ${produtos}" class="form-group" id="produtos">
       <label th:text="${produto.nome}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
       </label>
       <div class="col-sm-1">
           <input class="form-control js-number" id="quantPedido" th:field="*{products[__${produtoStat.index}__].quantPedido}"/>
       </div>
    </div>
    //...                                
</form>
```