# How to call a method in HTML(Thymeleaf, Spring, Java)?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

i'm beginner with Thymeleaf, but i want know how to call a method in HTML with Thymeleaf. I'm using Spring Boot with Spring MVC.

I want create a Button with a name like "Edit" and the user will edit the post of the blog, but if i want do that i have to know what's the ID from object Postagem.

My current code HTML: (blog.html)

```
            <div th:each="postagem : ${postagens}">
                <div class="blog-post">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title" th:text="${postagem.titulo}"></h2>
                    <p class="blog-post-meta">25 de dezembro de 2019 publicado por <a href="#">Vitor</a></p>
                    <p th:text="${postagem.texto}"></p>
                    <form action="#" th:action="@{/blog}" th:object="${postagem}" method="post">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" th:field="*{id}">Editar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.blog-post -->
            </div>
```

My current method in Java: (PostagemController.java)

```
@PostMapping("/blog")
public String edit(Postagem postagem) {
    for(Postagem post : postagens.findAll()) {
        if(post.getId() == postagem.getId()) {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("painel");
            modelAndView.addObject("postagemEdit", post);
            System.out.println("Id: " + post.getId());
            System.out.println("Título: " + post.getTitulo());
            System.out.println("Autor: " + post.getAutor());
            System.out.println("Texto: " + post.getTexto());
            break;
        }
    }
    return "redirect:/painel";
}
```

My current code on "painel.html" where is my form that I want set the information

```
    <form method="post" th:object="${postagemEdit}" th:action="@{/painel}" style="margin: 20px 0">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" th:field="*{titulo}" /> <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Spoiler do artigo" th:field="*{spoiler}" /><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Autor" th:field="*{autor}" /> <br>
            <textarea id="mytextarea" th:field="*{texto}"></textarea> <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publicar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can maintain a hidden field for post id in html like `input type = hidden`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf

Comment: AndrewG, that don't worked. I will update my topic with the current code

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not given the id a value in the html code. The default value for int in Java is 0 and that is possibly the reason why. Try to use 1 instead of *{id}.

If you are retrieving the blog post id and post content from the database which should be so then this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

### issues

1. No name
2. Value not set

   - solution 1

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/blog}" th:object="${postagem}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="btn btn-link" th:value="*{id}" />
  <button type=submit class="btn btn-link">Editar</button>
</form>
```

- solution 2

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/blog}" th:object="${postagem}" method="post">
<button name="id" type=submit class="btn btn-link" th:value="*{id}">Editar</button>
</form>
```

- solution 3

```js
    function myFunction(id) {
      var f = document.createElement("form")
      f.style.display="none"
      f.action="/action_page.php"
      f.method="get"
      var inp = document.createElement("input");
      inp.value=id
      inp.name="id"
      f.appendChild(inp);
      document.body.appendChild(f);
      f.submit();
    }
```

```html
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-link" th:data-id="*{id}" onclick='myFunction(this.getAttribute("data-id"))'>Editar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code that i used in the html template to call java class function

```
<small th:text="${T(com.sample.util.UIclass).textContent(instr)}"> </small>
```

And below is the java class for the method :

```
package com.sample.util;
import com.sample.models.Instr;

public class UIclass {
  public static String textContent(Instr instr)
    {
        return "Hello";
         
    }
}
```

In case if you need to access same in javascript following is the code

```
let d = [[${T(com.sample.UIclass).textContent(instr)}]];
console.log(d);
```