# How to send parametr to Controller properly? (Thymeleaf + Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am beginner at Thymeleaf. All I know is the fact that "Thymeleaf is not Javascript, it is rendered on server." I am making mistakes all the time because I am usually trying to use that Thymeleaf a little like JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<form th:action="@{/user/sqlCode}" method="post">
    <button id="newDatabase"></button>
</form>
<textarea id="generatedSql" readonly></textarea>
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(path = { "/user/sqlCode" })
public String createSchema(@RequestParam(???) String tmp) {
    String finallyMyValue = tmp;
    // STOP  I want to have data from generatedSql in this moment (finallyMyValue)
    // ...
}
```

***@ MISSION @*

1. Click button *(id: newDatabase)*

2. Get data from the textarea *(id: generatedSql)*

3. Send the value with that data to the controller

4. Be happy :)

*@ MISSION @***

I tried a lot of things but only using Javascript. Scenario is always the same, JavaScript is executed totally before Thymeleaf and finally I can't properly read that data... I tried that scenario:

1. Click button *(id: newDatabase)*
2. Get data from the textarea *(id: generatedSql)* **using JavaScript**
3. Insert that data into variable `name` in input tag **using JavaScript**
4. Send the variable `name` to the controller.
5. And here I always get NULL or error 404

Screenshot with my failed approach, which ended in a null at the breakpoint:
[image]

Comment: Check this example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try use Javascript with Ajax:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="submitData()">Change Content</button>
</div>

function submitData() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("post", "$URL", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```