# Thymeleaf - How to send an object (with child object) from form back to the Controller

Tags: forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'am trying to "send" a "complex" object from a thymeleaf form back to the controller.
I found this minimal example ([Send datas from html to controller in Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf)), which does basically the same thing (Works perfectly). The only difference is, that their object has a String attribute instead of an other object.

But once I replace the String Attribute with the bar object, the bar object is always null, when submitting the form. 
Is submitting nested objects even possible?

Objects

```java
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Bar {

    private String id;

    public Bar(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/showForm", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBar(new Bar("test"));
    model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
    return Pages.TEST;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="foo") Foo foo) {
    ...
    return Pages.TEST;
}
```

HTML

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{bar}"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind your input text to `id` field of `bar` object.

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{bar.id}"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The missing binding of the id field in the bar object was one issue. The other was the constructor in the Bar.class. Which, after binding the 'id' caused this exception:

`NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'bar' of bean class [Foo]: Could not instantiate property type [Bar] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Bar.<init>())`

After adding a default constructor to the Bar.class it worked.