# Field error trying to save object in Spring Boot & Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

First time making a project with Spring Boot and Hibernate, and I'm getting an error I don't know how to fix. Error occurs when trying to submit form to create a new yarn object.

The relevant controllers (HomeController.java):

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private BrandRepository brandRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ColorRepository colorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WeightRepository weightRepository;

    @Autowired
    private YarnRepository yarnRepository;

    @RequestMapping("")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "My Yarns");

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("yarn/add")
    public String displayAddYarnForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Add Yarn");
        model.addAttribute(new Yarn());
        model.addAttribute("colors", colorRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("brands", brandRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("weights", weightRepository.findAll());

        return "yarn/add";
    }

    @PostMapping("yarn/add")
    public String processAddYarnForm(@ModelAttribute Yarn newYarn, Error errors,
                                     Model model,
                                     @RequestParam (required = false) Integer brand,
                                     @RequestParam (required = false) Integer color,
                                     @RequestParam (required = false) Integer weight) {

        model.addAttribute("newYarn", newYarn);
        Optional<Brand> yarnBrand = brandRepository.findById(brand);
        Optional<Color> yarnColor = colorRepository.findById(color);
        Optional <Weight> yarnWeight = weightRepository.findById(weight);
        yarnRepository.save(newYarn);
        return "redirect:";
    }
}
```

The form (add.html):

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments :: head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div th:replace="fragments :: page-header"></div>

<div class="container body-content">
<form method="post" style="max-width:600px;">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label th:for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" th:field="${yarn.name}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label th:for="brand">Brand</label>
        <select th:field="${yarn.brand}">
            <option th:each="brand : ${brands}"
                    th:text="${brand.name}"
                    th:value="${brand.id}"></option>
        </select>
        <a th:href="@{'/brand/add'}">Add Brands</a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label th:for="color">Color</label>
        <select th:field="${yarn.color}">
            <option th:each="color : ${colors}"
                    th:text="${color.name}"
                    th:value="${color.id}"></option>
        </select>
        <a th:href="@{'/color/add'}">Add Colors</a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label th:for="weight">Weight</label>
        <select th:field="${yarn.weight}">
            <option th:each="weight : ${weights}"
                    th:text="${weight.name}"
                    th:value="${weight.id}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Yarn" />
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the Yarn model:

```java
@Entity
public class Yarn extends AbstractEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    private Brand brand;

    @ManyToOne
    private Weight weight;

    @ManyToOne
    private Color color;

    public Yarn() {
    }

    public Yarn(Brand brand, Weight weight, Color color) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Brand getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(Brand brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public Weight getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Weight weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

and the AbstractEntity class every model extends:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public AbstractEntity() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public AbstractEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AbstractEntity that = (AbstractEntity) o;
        return id == that.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

(I have models for color, weight, brand too but these seem redundant)
And the error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='yarn'. Error count: 3
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
Field error in object 'yarn' on field 'brand': rejected value [1]; codes [typeMismatch.yarn.brand,typeMismatch.brand,typeMismatch.one.philosopherstone.knittingconversions.models.Brand,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [yarn.brand,brand]; arguments []; default message [brand]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'one.philosopherstone.knittingconversions.models.Brand' for property 'brand'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'one.philosopherstone.knittingconversions.models.Brand' for property 'brand': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I'm not sure why the types sent by the form don't match, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Well it looks like you're trying to send a String (i think it's th:value="${brand.id}") instead of the brand itself which is a field of your entity. You should find a way to send the brand object from the frontend to the backend. I don't use Thymeleaf but i think it won't be so complicated.

Comment: When does this error occur? When you post the form or while you're getting it?

Comment: I edited the post, it occurs when I submit the form. Would it solve the problem to change the controller input parameters to strings, and then convert them to integers?

Comment: Well it's usually better to send an object which has all the parameters in it. I haven't used thymeleaf in the frontend but check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with this

`th:value="${brand.id}"></option>` in your HTML page.

Here we are supposed to pass a brand rather than it's id, just change it as given below
and you will also have to change it in color and weight selection.

`th:value="${brand}"></option>`

Comment: How would I change the controller to handle a brand object? Currently I'm using the brandRepository.findByID to find the brand in the existing brand object.

Comment: you will get that id in your brand object you get with newYarn object.

Comment: Optional<Brand> yarnBrand = brandRepository.findById(brand.getId()); returns the same error. As does newYarn.setBrand(brand);