# How to post thymeleaf form data to Controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

coders!
I have a question.

My thymeleaf form data don't post to Controller.
Here's my code.

thymeleaf

```html
    <form role="form" th:action="@{/board/insertBoard}" th:object="${boardDto}" method="post">
        <input type="text" th:value="${board.boardNo}">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{boardName}" th:value="test" placeholder="게시판 제목을 입력해주세요." aria-label="게시판 제목 삽입용 폼" required="required"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="insertBoard" type="submit">삽입</button>
    </form>
```

BoardDto

```
       private int boardNo;
    private String boardName;

    public int getBoardNo() {
        return boardNo;
    }
    public void setBoardNo(int boardNo) {
        this.boardNo = boardNo;
    }
    public String getBoardName() {
        return boardName;
    }
    public void setUserPwd(String boardName) {
        this.boardName = boardName;
    }
```

BoardController

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/board")
public class BoardController {

    @Autowired
    BoardService boardService = new BoardService();

    @Autowired
    PostService postService = new PostService();

    @GetMapping("/boardList/{boardNo}")
    ModelAndView board(@PathVariable(name="boardNo") Integer boardNo) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("board/list");
        mav.addObject("boardDto", new BoardDto());
        mav.addObject("board", boardService.selectBoardById(boardNo));
        mav.addObject("boardList", boardService.selectAllBoard());
        mav.addObject("postList", postService.selectPostByBoard(boardNo));

        return mav;
    }

    @PostMapping("/insertBoard")
    public ModelAndView insertBoard(@ModelAttribute("boardDto") BoardDto boardDto, BindingResult result,
    RedirectAttributes redirect, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("board/list");
        System.out.println("---------------------> board!!!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.println("---------------------> " + boardDto.getBoardNo());
        System.out.println("---------------------> " + boardDto.getBoardName());
        System.out.println("---------------------> board!!!!!!!!!!!");
        boardService.insertBoard(boardDto);
        mav.addObject("board", boardService.selectBoardById(boardDto.getBoardNo()));
        mav.addObject("boardList", boardService.selectAllBoard());
        mav.addObject("postList", postService.selectPostByBoard(boardDto.getBoardNo()));

        return mav;
    }

....
```

When I try to insert data, console return below sysout I made in Controller.

```
---------------------> board!!!!!!!!!!!
---------------------> 0
---------------------> null
---------------------> board!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I want to get data through @ModelAttribute in Controller.
How can i get this Dto data in Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself recently started to study Thymeleaf. I've seen that you try to get ModalAttribute with value `"boardPostData"` but in html you have another name: `th:object="${boardDto}"`. May be try to rename to `boardPostData` in html, or to `boardDto` in your controller?

Comment: Ahh.. I tried this various way and made a mistake there. Also @ModelAttribue("boardDto") BoardDto boardDto didn't work.

Comment: In this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf) i've seen, that setter and getter should named like your object, example: setBoardDto getBoardDto

Comment: Wow! thx!! A typing mistake in getter and setter. Thank you so much