# How Can I Send Data to Spring Controller by a tag html

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="start" id="start" required>
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="end" id="end" required>
```

and this is my a tag that I want to sent date to my Spring controller

```
<a  target="_blank" class="btn btn-info" id="search" th:href="@{/record/pdf?start={start}&end={end}}" >Print</a>
```

That I error HTTP Status 400

What I want like this

```
http://localhost:8082/record/pdf?start=2023-06-01&end=2023-06-14
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send datas from html to controller in Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the `start` and `end` dates provided in the input as Thymeleaf is a server-side templating engine, so wouldn't be able to access local parameters until they are posted to the server. You can consider the below solution for your problem.

On the form make the following changes

```
<form th:action="@{/fetch-pdf}" th:object="${pdfDates}" method="post">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" field="*{start}" name="start" required />
    <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" field="*{end}" name="end" required/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Print"/>
</form>
```

**PDFDates** is a model defined on the server side

```
public class PDFDates {
    private String start;
    private String end;

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public String getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
}
```

On the server side. Modify your controller to look like this

```
@Controller
public class FormInputHandler {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fetch-pdf",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RedirectView  getUserInput(@ModelAttribute PDFDates pdfDates, RedirectAttributes attributes){
        attributes.addAttribute("start", pdfDates.getStart());
        attributes.addAttribute("end", pdfDates.getEnd());
        return new RedirectView("/record/pdf");
    }
}
```

**Note that** the endpoint `http://localhost:3030/record/pdf?start=2023-06-07&end=2023-06-07` should be defined on the server side